# performSelectorOnMainThread equivalent in Java for Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an iPhone application and I am porting it over to Android.

I have a service/controller that spawns new threads to perform some network tasks.

I use `performSelectorOnMainThread` in my iPhone app. How can I have my Java app do the same or similar thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options:

1. manual threading + [Handler](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or `runOnUiThread(..)` available from Activity for posting UI changes
2. [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
3. [Service](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Service.html) for lengthy background operations

Comment: That's the answer if Mr. White wishes to replace his current threads plus handle updating the UI on the main application thread. And that's probably a good idea, as "threads" plural gets a wee bit scary.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `performSelectorOnMainThread` does what I think it does, look at `runOnUiThread()` in `Activity`, or `post()` on `Handler` or any of your `Views` (i.e., your GUI widgets).

Though I generally agree with alex's answer -- use `AsyncTask` where possible, rather than forking your own threads.